# PHP opendir( ) function problem

Tags: php

```
$result = 'false';
if( opendir( $this->OuterTemplateDirPath != false ) ){
   $result = 'true';
}
return $result;
```

I have that fxn and outertemplate is equal to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] . 'mysite.com/templates/admin/structure/outertemplate/`.

but it returns with an error saying:

```
Warning: opendir(1) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\mysite.com\templates\admin\structure\structure.php on line 411
```

what seems to be the problem? what should be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parentheses seem misplaced. You are passing a boolean (the return value of comparing the template directory to false) to opendir() instead of the directory.

```
if (opendir($this->OuterTemplateDirPath) != false) {
```

Comment: YEAH!! THanks alot! carelessness!! crap!